# Table not showing when trying to append in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search input with autocomplete and when I search a query and click on button - it should show me my table but for some reason it is not showing my table when a button is clicked. It just shows the `[object FormData]` and I need some help to fix this.

```
$(function () {
    var myData = [];

    $.get("http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function (data) {
        $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: myData
        }); 

        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            myData.push({
            id: v.id,
            label: v.label,
            value: v.id,    
        });
    });
});

$('#searchForm').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
    let searchValue = $('#searchTextField').val();
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
    fetch(url, {
        body: data,
        method: "post"
    }).then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
        $('#results').append(data + '<br/><br/>');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't stringify a formData object. Shouldn't you be inserting the text from response?

Comment: it shall not be a text but a html table

Comment: I did this in my body inside fetch: `JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: but did not work.

Comment: @charlietfl Means `$('#results').append(data + '<br/><br/>');` should probably be `$('#results').append(text + '<br/><br/>');`. There is no point in doing an ajax call and not use the response, it's highly unlikely you want to use `data` here. Also an object `FormData` cannot convert nicely to a string so it gives `[object FormData]` as the text.

Comment: it is working, but it is displaying my whole body of my page rather than just the table.

Comment: so, comment out `FormData`?

Comment: You can do something like `$('#results').append($(text).find('table'))`. Ideally you would only send what is actually needed rather than a whole page

Comment: The FormData is what you send to server in order for server to return appropriate response